# How to identify differences between two decision trees

Tags: r, clustering, cart

I have two decision trees that gives each individual a rating based on the same 4 parameters (two quantitative and one qualitative). They are supposed to be exactly the same, but give different results (which indicates some error).

I have the thresholds for one of them, but the ones for the other decision tree remain unknown.

I need to understand what happened to these results. It would really help me to know the differences between the two models.

I have access to both the inputs and outputs of the models.

I already tried to recreate the decision trees using `rpart` in R, but it didn't succeed.

```r
rpart(Model_output ~ Parameter1 + Parameter2 + Parameter3 + 
             Parameter4, data=data, method="class", 
             control=rpart.control(cp=0))
```

(I chose the full tree option because I assumed it would be simple, since the initial model is supposed to be simple).

Can someone help me ?

Comment: How do you have these two decision trees then if not in `rpart`? Can you look at some kind of summary  they have? They might have been created using different splitting criteria for example.

Comment: I just have the criteria for one decision tree. For the other, I just have the outputs. The inputs are shared between the two. They surely were created using different criteria, because they give different outputs, but I can't find which.